# TypeError: Services.get_settlement_postoffices() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settlement'

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

Trying this code :

```
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime
import json
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, List, Optional, Union

from pochta.enums import PostofficeWorkType
from pochta.utils import HTTPMethod


class Services:
    def get_settlement_postoffices(self, settlement: str,
                                   region: Optional[str] = None,
                                   district: Optional[str] = None) -> List[str]:
        url = '/postoffice/1.0/settlement.offices.codes'
        params = {
            'settlement': settlement,
            'region': region,
            'district': district,
        }
        res = self._client.request(HTTPMethod.GET, url, params=params)
        return res.json()
i = Services()
print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
```

but im getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Odo\Desktop\api\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
TypeError: Services.get_settlement_postoffices() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settlement'
```

please help me. im new to python. it would be nice seeing the whole code with solution of this problem

Comment: Well it's telling you you need a value for `settlement`, but you didn't pass in a value for it. So, your code should have `i.get_settlement_postoffices(settlement)`, where `settlement` is a string that contains a valid value. In the definition for the function `get_settlement_postoffices`, its `settlement` argument does not contain `Optional[str] = None` next to it like the others, meaning it is _not_ optional.

Comment: i ve typed for settlement a value like `settlement: str = None`
then i ve added  `def __init__(self):
        self._client = None` to my code cuz im getting an error `AttributeError: 'Services' object has no attribute '_client'` but even after that im getting an error `res = self._client.request(HTTPMethod.GET, url, params=params)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'`